# How do I change the formatting of individual pages?

Tags: layout

I'm using a document class that displays a colored bar in the header on every page. However, at one point in the document I want to insert a pdf which fills the entire page. Hence, I want the bar as well as the page numbering to disappear. How is that possible?

For reference:
[image]

Comment: Have you given `\thispagestyle{empty}` a try?

Comment: I have, but this doesn't seem to have any impact on my problem unfortunately. Maybe the formatting from the documentclass has higher priority?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How do you insert the pdf? Make sure that `\thispagetyle{empty} is on the same page as the pdf.